# Equivalent of attaching a listener to buttons on document ready in jQuery instead of vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

How do I convert this JavaScript code to jQuery code?

```js
if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
} else {
    ready()
}

function ready() {
    var removeCartItemButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-danger')
    for (var i = 0; i < removeCartItemButtons.length; i++) {
        var button = removeCartItemButtons[i]
        button.addEventListener('click', removeCartItem)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running something when the document is ready is handled by the [$( document ).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) method.

`getElementByClassName` can be replaced by a [Class Selector (".class")](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Your `for` loop can be removed because with jQuery methods all are called on each returned element.

`addEventListener` can be replaced by [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/).

Then your code is just three lines long:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.btn-danger').click(removeCartItem)
})
```

Answer (score -3):

jQuery is a library of Javascript, and therefore nothing needs to be converted. -I just looked back at this and cant believe how stupid this is

Comment: While this is technically true, jQuery has the potential to make the code much shorter in this case.